# Break A List of Strings into Individual Rows

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataframe of recipes that contains two columns: a list of ingredients formatted this way:

Ingredient----------------------Average Review

['eggs', 'flour', 'sugar']-------4.7

I'm trying to unpack the ingredients column and give it a row for each individual ingredient string, with the result looking like this:

Ingredient:-------Average Review:

'eggs'-------------4.7

'flour'-------------4.7

'sugar'-----------4.7

The idea is to aggregate the data after doing this and come up with an average review for the recipes containing each ingredient. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a string, one option is to remove the square brackets with `str_remove_all`, then use `separate_rows` to split the 'Ingredient' at the `,` to expand the rows

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Ingredient = str_remove_all(Ingredient, "\\[|\\]|'")) %>%
    separate_rows(Ingredient, sep=",\\s*")
#   Ingredient AverageReview
#1       eggs           4.7
#2      flour           4.7
#3      sugar           4.7
```

---

Or another option is to extract the words into a `list` and then do `unnest`

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Ingredient = str_extract_all(Ingredient, "[[:alpha:]]+")) %>%
    unnest(c(Ingredient))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Ingredient AverageReview
#  <chr>              <dbl>
#1 eggs                 4.7
#2 flour                4.7
#3 sugar                4.7
```

---

Or in `base R` with `regmatches/gregexpr` to extract the words into a `list` and then construct the 'data.frame'

```
lst1 <- regmatches(df1$Ingredient, gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]+", df1$Ingredient))
data.frame(Ingredient = unlist(lst1), AverageReview = rep(df1$AverageReview,, lengths(lst1)))
#  Ingredient AverageReview
#1       eggs           4.7
#2      flour           4.7
#3      sugar           4.7
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- data.frame(Ingredient = "['eggs', 'flour', 'sugar']",
                   AverageReview = 4.7, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```